# How do I refresh the page when back button is pressed?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In an ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app, how do I refresh a page and load a fresh page after the back button is pressed?

Comment: Which back button? the browser back button? Are you developing SPA?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No. I am not developing an SPA. I have a .net core web app and I am submitting a form through ajax which redirects to another page after submission. But the problem arises when i press the back button the form data appears which may result in duplicate data being submitted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At your `layout.cshtml` just use this `javascript` code

```
<script>

    if (performance.navigation.type == 2) {
      location.reload();
    }

</script>
```